# Incorrect file position after fwrite call in Solaris11.3 OS

Tags: c++, io, solaris

I came across a problem when writing a binary file. In order to debug the problem, I made the output file stream un-buffered by call `setbuf(pf,0)`. Following is part of the code that represents the problem. Before calling `fwrite`, `pos0=943195`. By calling `fwrite` I wrote an int number to the file. However,after calling `fwrite`, `pos=943200`, which should be **943199** I think.

```
    FILE* pf = NULL;
    pfSenc = fopen(szFilePath, "r+b");
    setbuf(pfSenc, 0);
    // lots of read and write operations on this file
    int pos0 = ftell(pf);
    fwrite(&some_num, sizeof(int), 1, pf);
    int pos = ftell(pf);
    // more read and write operations on this file.
    fclose(pf);
```

Is this some kind of alignment requirements when writing binary file in Solaris OS? Since 943195 can not be divided by 4, so `fwrite` starts at 943196? The content written to file also shows that fwrite starts write with 1 byte offset. If it is an alignment problem, can this feature be disabled somehow? The code works as expected in other OSs like Windows and Centos7.

**Update：**
The following system calls:

```
1334: llseek(18, 0, SEEK_CUR)    = 943195
1334: write(18, "B1", 1)    = 1
1334: write(18, " !CC13\0", 4)   = 4
1334: llseek(18, 0, SEEK_CUR)    = 943200
```

are generated by this 3 lines of code:

```
int pos0 = ftell(pf);
fwrite(&some_num, sizeof(int), 1, pf);
int pos = ftell(pf);
```

There is an unexpected extra write call before write the int number:

```
1334: write(18, "B1", 1)    = 1
```

I have no idea where this call comes from? This application is single-threaded and the file is not opened anywhere else.

Comment: *Is this some kind of alignment requirements when writing binary fine in Solaris OS?* It shouldn't be.  What do you mean by "The content written to file also shows that fwrite starts write with 1 byte offset."?  Can you post a minimal and complete example that isolates the issue?

Comment: Chances are it is some bug in your program.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I check the file content and found the int that is written to file starts at position 943196, not 943195 which is the current file position.

Comment: What do your other read and especially write operations do? Are you writing any structures to the file?  How do you know your `pos0` and `pos` values differ by 5 instead of by `sizeof( int )`? Also, `ftell()` returns `long`, and not `int`.  If there does happen to be a bug somewhere, the small bit of code you're provided is not going to be enough for anyone else to replicate it.

Comment: There are some structures been written to the file. Print out pos0 and pos values by GDB?  I'm sorry there is too much code, however they are mostly read and write operations. Is it the "r+b" mode cause the problem maybe?

Comment: If there are no such things as file write alignment. Maybe I should double-check the code.

Comment: *Is it the "r+b" mode cause the problem maybe?* I'd hope not. If there's a bug in any of the tools you're using, I'd first suspect GDB, in all honesty, especially if you're running Solaris on SPARC hardware.  It's not that hard to write code on Solaris/SPARC that will fail to run if compiled with GCC. I suspect something else is going on.  The question is what.  You can run your process under `truss` and see the exact system calls made.  Your `ftell()` calls should translate directly to `lseek()` system calls in the truss output.  `truss -f -a -vall -o /path/to/output/file yourProgram ...`

Comment: Note also that Solaris provides three completely different implementations of the standard C `FILE *`-based IO functions from `stdio.h`.  "Legacy" 32-bit, "extended" 32-bit, and the 64-bit implementation. So your compiler options really matter here, too. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54766/enable-extended-file-stdio-3c.html and  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54776/extendedfile-5.html#REFMAN5extendedfile-5

Comment: @AndrewHenle I updated the question with system calls been made. Does it ring any bells? Thanks.

Comment: That is something very strange.  It's almost as if there's data in the buffer despite `setbuf()` being used to set the buffer to zero.  What happens if you replace `fwrite(&some_num, sizeof(int), 1, pf);` with `fflush(pf);`?  If there is data in the buffer, the one-byte write will remain.  If both the single byte write and the four-byte write both disappear, then it's probably time to dig into using `dtrace` to figure out what's going on, because that would be *very* strange.  Also, do post your compiler and link command(s) used to build your application.  One quick test - compile as 64-bit.

Comment: Solaris also provides the `sotruss` utility, which traces library calls into shared objects in the same manner that `truss` traces system calls into the kernel. `sotruss -o /some/output/file yourProgram ...`.  That would trace all library calls made by your main program to functions in any shared object. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/sotruss-1.html  Also, post the output from `pldd PID` where `PID` is the process ID of your running program. I'd love to see if it's pulling in some shared object from someplace unexpected.

Comment: Also, this is just a hunch, but try reversing the arguments to `fwrite()` and checking the return value from `fwrite()` - that way you can see what actually gets passed. Change `fwrite(&some_num, sizeof(int), 1, pf);` to `size_t bytesWritten = fwrite(&some_num, 1, sizeof(int), pf);`  Also, would `some_num` happen to be an `int` field in a packed structure?

Comment: @AndrewHenle We didn't try `sotruss` or `dtrace` yet. But we add a `fflush(pf)` before writing the some_num and things work correctly. No extra byte written to file. And we saw a `llseek()` system call generated by fflush. As you said it seems there is a buffer although we set the buffer to 0. We'll dig deeper to see if we can find more. BTW, some_num is not a field of a structure.

Comment: We jump back and forth in the file to read and write data, maybe there are chances that we crashed the i/o buffer. We are trying to find the bug.